# Java: Timer doesn't excute while rest of the method does

Tags: java

In the code below is a method that gets called when a user clicks on a JLabel in a GUI. The method is passed the coördinates in the pos[] integer list, and the current position of the 'player' is accessed by m.findPosition(), which also returns an integer list. Everything inside the method works properly, except the timer that gets started. The code inside the timer just doesn't execute, everything else does. I also noticed that after I clicked on a JLabel, neither Keyboard nor Mouse events are registered. My gut says that the timer does get executed but somehow the code inside it not?

Thanks in advance guys!

PS: I have also tried to put Try&Catch around it, but I didn't get a single error.

Note: The .moveMatrix() function takes a direction('l' is left, 'u' up, etc) and then moves the object in that direction by 1. The 4 cases (have to move up or down and have to move left or right) are checked here, to move to a certain position. The timers should keep repeating till the difference between the actual position and the wanted position(pos[]) is 0 for each coordinate.

```
            int timertime = 500;
            int[] officialpos = m.findPosition();
            System.out.println(officialpos[0] + "," + officialpos[1]);
            System.out.println(pos[0] + "," + pos[1]);
            int dx = pos[1] - officialpos[1];
            int dy = pos[0] - officialpos[0];
            System.out.println(dx);
            System.out.println(dy);
            if (dy > 0) {

                Timer time_down = new Timer(timertime, new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                        System.out.println("test");
                        m.moveMatrix('d');
                        updateMatrix(m, true);
                        System.out.println(m.findPosition()[1] + "," + m.findPosition()[0]);

                    }
                });
                time_down.start();

                while (pos[0] - m.findPosition()[0] > 0) {

                }
                time_down.stop();

            } else if (dy < 0) {
                System.out.println("dy < 0, dus omhoog");
                Timer time_up = new Timer(timertime, new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                        System.out.println("test");
                        m.moveMatrix('u');
                        updateMatrix(m, true);
                        System.out.println(m.findPosition()[1] + "," + m.findPosition()[0]);

                    }
                });

                time_up.start();
                while (pos[0] - m.findPosition()[0] < 0) {

                }
                time_up.stop();

            }
            if (dx > 0) {
                System.out.println("dx > 0, dus naar rechts");
                Timer time_right = new Timer(timertime, new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                        System.out.println("test");
                        m.moveMatrix('r');
                        updateMatrix(m, true);
                        System.out.println(m.findPosition()[1] + "," + m.findPosition()[0]);

                    }
                });
                time_right.start();

                while ((pos[1] - m.findPosition()[1]) > 0) {

                }
                time_right.stop();

            } else if (dx < 0) {
                System.out.println("dx < 0, dus naar links");
                Timer time_left = new Timer(timertime, new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                        System.out.println("test");
                        m.moveMatrix('l');
                        updateMatrix(m, true);
                        System.out.println(m.findPosition()[1] + "," + m.findPosition()[0]);

                    }
                });
                System.out.println("starting timer");
                time_left.start();

                System.out.println("Timer started");
                while (pos[1] - m.findPosition()[1] < 0) {

                    // System.out.println("waiting");
                }
                time_left.stop();
            }
```

Comment: [mcve] would be useful...

Comment: Can you run in a debugger? I'd make sure the while loop is blocking long enough for the thread to start before you call stop()